# What are the values ​of the variables a and b in this code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

```
#include<iostream>
struct Vector2
{
    int x, y;
};
struct Vector4
{
public:
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            int x, y, z, w;
        };
        struct
        {
            Vector2 a, b;
        };
    };
};
void PrintVector(const Vector2& vector)
{
    std::cout << vector.x << ", " << vector.y << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    Vector4 vector4 = { 1,2,3,4 };
    vector4.x = 50;
    PrintVector(vector4.a);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

In this code, why does a have values ​​of x and y, and b has values ​​of z and w? Is it related to Union?
Let me know if you know.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The initialisation `{ 1,2,3,4 }` makes the first `struct` in the `union` the *active member*.

The statement `vector4.x = 1;` is valid since you're manipulating an element of the active member.

The behavior of reading `vector4.a` is **undefined** as the second `struct` in the `union` is **not** the active member.

Type punning through a `union` is not allowed in C++ in general. In other words, `a` and `b` don't have a value.

Comment: ...though this trick is not unusual and seemed to work, at least, in the past in the one or other compiler. I believe it's meant to provide something like the [swizzling in GLSL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling). Sometimes, the prohibition of type-punning in C++ really hurts. ;-)

Comment: PrintVector(vector4.a); vector4.a does nothing and PrintVector() function ignores vector4.a and executes the contents of the function?

Comment: @SeungYup26 Undefined Behavior means that it's not defined (concerning the language standard) what `PrintVector()` actually does. At best, it might print a Vector2 with the contents of `vector4.x` and `vector4.y`. It could also print anything or just crash.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is undefined behavior, but most compilers will support it ([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#:%7E:text=It%27s%20undefined%20behavior%20to%20read,inactive%20members%20of%20a%20union.&text=Each%20member%20is%20allocated%20as,only%20member%20of%20the%20class.)):

> It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written. Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union.

Here's a simple example illustrating the same concept, without the extra structs:

```
union ExampleUnion {
  int a;
  int b;
};

int main() 
{
  ExampleUnion e;
  e.a = 1;
  // This will print 1, since b occupies the same memory as a.
  std::cout << e.b << std::endl;
}
```

It works because the size of a union is the max size of the largest member (not the sum of member sizes). This means the members share the same memory, so if you write to one you can read from another.